# Issue with Tile and Icon with Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

I have completed my Windows 10 App and now I want to send it to my clients. So, I was trying to create AppPackage to upload it, when I did that, I am getting following error

```
2>MakePRI : warning 0xdef01051: No default or neutral resource given for 'Files/Assets/Square44x44Logo.png'. The application may throw an exception for certain user configurations when retrieving the resources.
2>F:\Company\Windows 10\MCS\MCS\Package.appxmanifest(18,73): error APPX1619: App manifest references the square 150x150 logo image 'Assets\300.png' which does not have valid dimensions. It must be 150x150 pixels.
2>F:\Company\Windows 10\MCS\MCS\Package.appxmanifest(19,26): error APPX1619: App manifest references the wide 310x150 logo image 'Assets\620.png' which does not have valid dimensions. It must be 310x150 pixels.
2>F:\Company\Windows 10\MCS\MCS\Package.appxmanifest(18,108): error APPX1619: App manifest references the small logo image 'Assets\88.png' which does not have valid dimensions. It must be 44x44 pixels.
```

I changed and added correct images, then also it is not working properly. Can someone suggest me what is the issue? Is there any particular naming convention that needs to be taken care?

Comment: Have you checked size in pixels of images 300.png, 620.png etc.?

Comment: Yes, instead of that I added other image with 150*150 etc then also showing error

Comment: Try to rename images to it's default names

Comment: your app can access previous app package try to remove it from App_Package folder and create new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check images if there are exactly the dimensions that are needed. For example if picture size should be 150x150 and you have it 151x151 then an error will occur. Add the images from package.manifest and don't change them name, just replace the previous ones. Make sure you have added all those image sizes:

1. 300x300
2. 620x300
3. 88x88
4. 24x24
5. 50x50
6. 1240x600 (splash)

Also you can run [windows app certification kit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/app-certification-kit) to examine app for errors.

Hope it helps